# Create uncorrelated random multivariate normals

Tags: r, correlation, random-generation

Creating correlated random variables is an easy task in R, especially the normal distribution. But what I need is to generate variables (for example 5 standard normals) with very low correlations (e.g., below 0.05). I tried `mvtnorm` package several times with no success.

I'm just curious, we use methods (like Cholesky decomposition) to transform uncorrelated variables into correlated. Can we do it the other way around?

**Edit:** I want a method that makes multiple "correlated" normal variables "extremely low correlated" without trial & error with a reasonable sample size (say 50) implemented in R.

Comment: In what way was mvtnorm unsuccessful?!

Comment: Is your problem that the sample correlation isn't identical to your specified (population) correlation?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, somehow.

Comment: Since I assume you realize that the sample correlation simply won't equal the population correlation, I think you're going to have to clarify what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X$ is multivariate normal.

Then by definition we can write $X = \mu + CZ$ for a (deterministic) vector $\mu$, matrix $C$ and random vector $Z$ of independent standard normal (i.e. $N(0,1)$) variables.

(So $\Sigma = CC^T$ is the covariance matrix).

Thus if $C$ is invertible then 
$$
C^{-1}(X-\mu) = Z
$$
is a vector of independent (and hence uncorrelated) standard normals.

Note, if you are given pos. def. $\Sigma$ upfront, then to calculate $C = (\Sigma^{1/2})^{-1}$ you would probably want to first calculate the square root (e.g. using Cholesky) and then invert that.

Comment: I can't tell which question you are answering: are you trying to explain how to create correlated variables (which is the objective of the links you provide) or *uncorrelated* variables (which appears to be what is asked on the last line)?

Comment: Yes on rereading that is probably what the OP wants, and the answer I linked to is the wrong way round -- will edit it later.  In the meantime, short answer: yes you can go from (non-singular) multivariate normal to uncorrelated normal but you need to calculate the inverse square root of the covariance matrix

Comment: Why not suggest PCA?

Comment: @P.Windridge nice. would you please represent it  with an example in R?

Answer (score 0):

Independent random variables should by definition not be correlated, but if you are only generating a small number of points you'll get some correlation by chance. You should find as you generate a larger dataset that you get lower correlations.

If, for some reason, you need to generate a small dataset with extremely low correlations between your five variables, you might instead generate say 50 variables, calculate their correlation matrix and select 5 with the lowest correlation.

Comment: thanks for the tip. by the way I was taking n=50 for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://yingqijing.medium.com/multivariate-normal-distribution-and-cholesky-decomposition-in-stan-d9244b9aa623), where I borrowed the idea from. I think this is what you were asking for.

```
# Number of variables to make
n <- 5

# Correlation Matrix with .05 correlation for all
R <- matrix(.05, nrow = n, ncol = n)
diag(R) <- 1

# Cholesky decompostion of correlation matrix
Lut <- chol(R)
L <- t(Lut)

# Standard deviations
sds <- seq(10, 1, length.out = n)

# VCOV matrix
Sigma <- diag(sds) %*% L %*% Lut %*% diag(sds)

# Generate variables
library(MASS)
X <- mvrnorm(50, mu= rep(0, n), Sigma, empirical = TRUE)
cov(X)
cor(X)

X <- mvrnorm(500, mu= rep(0, n), Sigma, empirical = FALSE)
cov(X)
cor(X)
```